# Compute Engine restrict SSH user to specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, google-compute-engine

How to create a new user that could connect Compute Engine instance via SSH but only access `/var/www/[username]/html`

My instance is running Ubuntu 16.04

Currently, I have only the root user.

Ultimate goal is to create an user that could then connect the instance using Filezilla but would have access only to the specified directory.